# php - Dropdown box value can't be inserted into MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I have made a dropdown list to choose the priority level of one contact, priority is an attribute to the table `person` and it has the type `ENUM`. The dropdown list is in a HTML-Form and I want to submit it to the MySQL database. But somehow the value can't be inserted. Can someone help me?

**Code**

```
//PHP
  if(isset($_POST["priority"]) && $_POST["priority"] == 'not_selected'){
    $err_priority = "Please assign the priority level!";
  }
  else {
    $priority = $_POST["priority"];
  }

  $sql1 = "INSERT INTO person (priority) VALUES (?)";
if ($stmt1 = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql1) or die(mysqli_error($conn))) {
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt1, 's', $priority);
}
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt1);
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt1);



//HTML-Form
  <div class="form-group <?php echo(!empty($err_priority)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
    <label>Priority</label>
    <?php
      echo '<select name="priority">';
      $sql = "SELECT COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'person' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'priority'";
      $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
      $enumlist = explode(  ",", str_replace("'", "", substr($row['COLUMN_TYPE'], 5, (strlen($row['COLUMN_TYPE'])-6))));

      foreach ($enumlist as $value_p) {
        echo '<option value="$value_p">'.$value_p.'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    ?>
    <span class="help-block"><?php echo "$err_priority"; ?></span>
  </div>
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="submit" class="btnsml" value="Add Contact">
</div>
```

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Horrible code design...free hint: dont mix layout, logic and data.. read/think about _separation of concerns_ instead

Comment: This code is very hard to read, because you switch in and out of PHP far too often. You should really do all of your layout in plain HTML, and then fill in the data with PHP.

Comment: @B001ᛦ Thank you for your advices. I’m very new to PHP so I still have a lot to learn :P   I was playing with some ideas and basically just wrote what came into my mind into to the code...I’ll get rid of this bad habit ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
echo '<option value="$value_p">'.$value_p.'</option >';
```

You're not interpolating the contents of `$value_p`.
Change it, like this:

```
echo '<option value="' . $value_p . '">' . $value_p . '</option >';
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not setting the values in the select tag.

```
 echo '<select>';
 foreach ($enumlist as $value_p) {
        echo '<option value="'.$value_p.'">'.$value_p.'</value>';
 }
 echo '</select>';
```